# moving monolithic to Microservices

Tags: asp.net, refactoring, microservices

Our development team has decided to refactor an asp.net web app monolithic architecture to micro services. Consider we are planned for 4 microservices. Each microservice will be considered as a asp.net web app.

So, there are totally 4 web based microservices running in iis. Each has different domain name. All my 4 microservices have same master page. In microservice 1, i am having a link to navigate to microservice 2,3,4. Currently i am in microservice 1(the url is http://service1.com/home.aspx).

On clicking the menu to navigate to microservice 2, i need to redirect to the domain where it is hosted.Example http:service2/orders.aspx. This looks the url will be changing on menu click. How to overcome this problem? OR anything wat i mentioned is wrong approach.....please suggest a solution

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of would be to register [subdomains](https://godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-subdomain-296) (e.g. serv1.domain.com -> IP of service1, serv2.domain.com -> IP of service2). Another approach would be to have a single front-end application and multiple back-end services, which you could then consolidate using something like an API gateway. But implementing microservices **is hard**. So I'd suggest you try to fully understand how to implement it and why are microservices the best solution for you before going further if you haven't already.

Comment: Microservices are normally Web APIs based and common front end that would use backend micro services to render the views. So your UI is shared and can be hosted anywhere you like and you would be using backend APIs to get the data. Each microservices having a UI part is not a right approach.